# Can an interface method be overridden with a different Number return type?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashcode

I have a lab for data structures and the teacher asks me "create 'class IpAddressValueHasher implements Hasher' so when you
override hash(IpAddress) it returns a Long object for the parameter's
ipValue's call to hashCode.
The problem is that I don't know how to override the interface (which returns an int) which a method that returns a long.

Any help or pointers would be great thanks

```
public class IpAddressValueHasher implements Hasher<IpAddress> {
    @Override
    public long hash(IpAddress ip) { //error on this line, can't return long
        long ipValue = ip.getIpValue();
        return ipValue;
    }
}


public class IpAddress //new class
{   
    private long ipValue=0;
    private String dottedDecimal="0.0.0.0";

    public IpAddress(){}

    public IpAddress(String dec)
    {
        setDottedDecimal(dec);
    }

    public boolean setDottedDecimal( String s )
    {
        if( s==null || s.length() == 0 )
            return false;
        dottedDecimal = s;
        ipValue = 0;
        String [] tokens = s.split("[.]");
        for( String tok : tokens ){
            int subVal = Integer.parseInt(tok);
            ipValue  =  ipValue * 256 + subVal;
        } // end for
        return true;
    }

    public long getIpValue(){ return ipValue; }

    public String getDottedDecimal(){ return dottedDecimal; }

    public String toString(){ return dottedDecimal  + ", " + Long.toHexString(ipValue); }
} // end class IpAddress

public interface Hasher<E> {
    public int hash(E elem);
}
```

Comment: `public interface Hasher<K, V> { public V hash(K elem); }`

Comment: I'm don't think I can change the interface itself, as that code was provided by the teacher. Is there anyway to do this only while creating the new class code?

Comment: You cant, the point of an interface is that it defines the interface. Elloitts suggestion is the only way to achieve this

Comment: You can't - but it's also worth pointing out that you aren't returning a `Long` **object** either, you are returning a `long` primitive

Comment: This really isn't possible. You should ask your teacher for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, **Covariant Return Type** doesn't work with primitive data type. By covariant return type we mean that the return type may vary in the same direction as that of the subclass. It means that when we are overriding methods, then the return type of that method can be a subtype of the overridden method’s return type. For example -

```
    public class A {
        public Object method() {return null;}
    }
    public class B extends A {
        @Override
        public String method() {return "";}
    }
```

In your case, you can do following change :

```
    public class IpAddressValueHasher implements Hasher<IpAddress> {
         @Override
         public Long hash(IpAddress ip) { // This line 
             long ipValue = ip.getIpValue();
             return ipValue;
         }
    }
    interface Hasher<E> {
         public Number hash(E elem); // This line
    }
```